# Array gera erro "Undefined offset"

Tags: php

Boa tarde
Estou finalizando um script que fará algumas atualizações em nossos site
Possuo um array que no início contém todos os clientes da empresa e conforme o script é rodado, alguns são retirados. No final, os clientes que sobram no array devem ser atualizados com o Status INATIVO em nosso site.
O problema é que alguns registros que sobram neste array estão retornando esta mensagem de erro.

Segue trecho do código -

```
echo "Existem ".count($array_codigos) . " registros no banco SQL<br>";
                arsort($array_codigos);
                for($iy = 0; $iy <= count($array_codigos); $iy++){
                    $num++;
                    /******************************************************************
                     *   Deleta os clientes inexistentes do banco DBF do banco SQL    *
                     * Tabelas: Clientes, Contratos, Pagamentos, Boletos e Usuários   *
                     ******************************************************************/
                     $codigo_cliente = $array_codigos[$iy];
                     // TABELA CLIENTE
                    $consulta_cli = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cod_cliente = '$codigo_cliente'");

                    $num_cli = mysql_num_rows($consulta_cli);
                    if($num_cli != 0){
                        $array_cli = mysql_fetch_array($consulta_cli);
                        $status = $array_cli['status_cli'];
                        $nome_cliente = $array_cli['nome_cliente'];
                        if($status_cli != 'I'){
                            $update_inativo = mysql_query("UPDATE clientes SET status_cli = 'I' WHERE cod_cliente = $codigo_cliente");
                            if($update_inativo){
                                $inativos++;
                                echo "$iy - $codigo_cliente - $nome_cliente não existe no DBF - Atualizado para Inativo<br>";
                                $delete_users = mysql_query("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE cod_cliente = $codigo_cliente");

                            }else{
                                $erro = mysql_error();
                                echo "$erro";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

O código é bem extenso, caso seja necessário, posto outras informações.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Qual seria a linha 779? Deduzindo o erro, o problema estaria aqui: '$codigo_cliente = $array_codigos[$iy]'. Se os usuários, sua array, não está ordenada 0, 1, 2, 3....  Isso irá ocorrer.

Comment: Na segunda linha do seu código (aqui postado!), edite o `arsort($array_codigos);` para `$array_codigos = array_values ($array_codigos)`. Verifique se o mesmo problema persiste.

Answer (score 8):

O problema de índice ocorre SEMPRE que está a procurar um indice na array que não existe.

## Pequenos exemplos:

Em caso de uma array de índices numéricos:

```
<?php
$array = array('Ricdun', 'Markferum', 'Phiaan');
$indice = 3;

echo $array[ $indice ];
```

Nesse caso irá resultar:

```
NOTICE Undefined offset: 3 on line number 4
```

> *Lembre-se que array deste tipo sempre começa em zero, portanto o último elemento seria `2`.*

Em caso de array cujo o indice não seja númerico, como:

```
$array = array('indice' => 'valor', 'nome' => 'Jenord', 'idade' => '12');

// Exibe nome:
echo $array[ 'nome' ]
// Ok! 

// Exibe pais:
echo $array[ 'pais' ]
// Erro!
```

Isso ocorre porque não existe o índice com o nome `pais`, portanto o mesmo erro será retornado.

## Aplicação no seu caso:

No seu caso, o que pode ocorrer é isto:

```
$array = array(
0 => 'Maria',
1 => 'Ana',
3 => 'João',
4 => 'Pedro',
7 => 'Lucas',
8 => 'Vitor',
9 => 'Luisa',
11 => 'Gustavo'
);

for($i = 0; $i <  count($array); $i++){
echo $array[$i];
echo '<br>';
}
```

Observe que o índice não mantem uma ordem exata, por exemplo, não existe o índice de número 2, 5, 6 e nem o de número 10, mas vou chegar lá.

> Nota: A falta de ordem no índice promove dois problemas!

```
Maria
Ana

NOTICE Undefined offset: 2 on line number 13

João
Pedro

NOTICE Undefined offset: 5 on line number 13


NOTICE Undefined offset: 6 on line number 13

Lucas
```

Observe que o próprio PHP aponta os índices ausente. Porém note que ele não irá mostrar o resultado de "`Vitor`", "`Luisa`" e "`Gustavo`" e nem mesmo aponta erro no índice `10`.

Isso ocorre porque existem de fato apenas 8 elementos, porém o último índice é de 11, superior ao número que será obtido no `count()`. Dessa forma o loop é encerrado quando `$i < 8`, portanto irá encerrar em `7`, parando em "`Lucas`".

### Correção:

Existem duas formas fácies de corrigir esta situação.

#### 1. `Foreach`:

Substitua o `for()` por `foreach`.

```
$array = array(0 => 'Maria', 1 => 'Ana', 3 => 'João', 4 => 'Pedro', 7 => 'Lucas', 8 => 'Vitor', 9 => 'Luisa', 11 => 'Gustavo');

foreach($array as $indice => $valor){

  echo '| Valor: '.$valor;
  echo '<br>';
  echo '| Indice: '.$indice;
  echo '<br><br>';

}
```

Resultado:

```
| Valor: Maria
| Indice: 0

| Valor: Ana
| Indice: 1

| Valor: João
| Indice: 3

| Valor: Pedro
| Indice: 4

| Valor: Lucas
| Indice: 7

| Valor: Vitor
| Indice: 8

| Valor: Luisa
| Indice: 9

| Valor: Gustavo
| Indice: 11
```

A diferença, como pode perceber, é que o `foreach` automaticamente ignora os indices inexistentes. Para o `foreach` não importa qual o indice utilizado.

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

> Este método é recomendado porque o `indice` se mantem o mesmo!

#### 2. `array_values () + [loop]`:

Caso o índice não importe e não necessite dele, você pode usar o `array_values`, dessa forma ele irá reescrever a array em uma nova, essa possuindo a ordem correta.

```
$array = array(0 => 'Maria', 1 => 'Ana', 3 => 'João', 4 => 'Pedro', 7 => 'Lucas', 8 => 'Vitor', 9 => 'Luisa', 11 => 'Gustavo');

$array = array_values ( $array );

for($indice = 0; $indice <  count($array); $indice++){

  echo '| Valor: '.$array[ $indice ];
  echo '<br>';
  echo '| Indice: '.$indice;
  echo '<br><br>';

}
```

Resultando:

```
| Valor: Maria
| Indice: 0

| Valor: Ana
| Indice: 1

| Valor: João
| Indice: 2

| Valor: Pedro
| Indice: 3

| Valor: Lucas
| Indice: 4

| Valor: Vitor
| Indice: 5

| Valor: Luisa
| Indice: 6

| Valor: Gustavo
| Indice: 7
```

Verifique que neste caso o `Indice` é alterado, dessa forma ele mantem a ordem de 0 até o 7.  Portanto a antiga condição de `$i < 8` se enquadra corretamente.