# Porcentagem com PHP com ifs

Tags: php

Eu recebo 4 porcentagens e eu faço a média dividindo por 4. O Problema é que as vezes 1 ou duas porcentagens vem com 0 e se eu dividir por 4 não vai dar o resultado certo.

Como eu posso fazer isso? Estou com dificuldade de pensar algo lógico. Eu fiz isso até agora e funciona se os 4 estão preenchidos.

```
    <?php

if(($mediaQualidade != 0) and ($mediaSupervisores != 0) and ($mediaProcessos != 0) and ($mediaDpp != 0)) {
    $mediaTotal = (($mediaQualidade + $mediaSupervisores + $mediaProcessos + $mediaDpp)/4);
}
?>
```

Comment: E qual sua dúvida? O que quer fazer? Isto parece correto.

Comment: Se vem alguma zerada você deveria dividir apenas por 3 ou 2? Matematicamente falando, se um valor vem zerado ele não tem contribuição com o total e, por isso, abaixa a média. Isto é, faz sentido dividir por 4 mesmo vindo algum 0, mas, obviamente, depende muito do que você está fazendo e, por enquanto, só você sabe isso.

Comment: Ricardo Gonçalves, não sei se é isso que vc quer, veja uma opção com o B A BA do PHP nesse link https://rextester.com/IZTK96971. Você pode mudar os valores das variáveis e clicar no botão `Run it` para ver o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom sua pergunta está bem confusa , mas pelo que entendi as porcentagens que você recebe podem ser nulas em algum momento e você não quer que essa porcentagem nula entre no calculo, certo?

Nesse caso uma das possibilidades e você trabalhar com arrays:

```
 //Aqui você monta um array com a variáveis que precisa
 $aux = array ($mediaQualidade ,$mediaSupervisores ,$mediaProcessos,$mediaDpp);
 $valores = array();

 //aqui você procura pelos valores nulos e percorre cada posição do vetor
 for($i=0 ; $i < count($aux);$i++)
 {
   //Nesse IF você pega apenas os valores que não são 0
   if($aux[$i] != 0)
   {
    $valores[$i] = $aux[$i];
   }
 }
 //A partir dai basta você utilizar a função array_sum que vai somar todos os itens do array $valores e dividir por 4
 $mediaTotal = ((array_sum($valores))/4) ;
 echo " Sua média é : $mediaTotal" ;
```

Obs:Caso o divisor varie de acordo com a quantidade de elementos, basta você utilizar o count no seguinte esquema `$divisor = count ($valores);` e colocar a variável `$divisor` no lugar do `/4`

link da documentação do funcionamento do array_sum:http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-sum.php

link do porque utilizei o count dentro do for : [Array gera erro "Undefined offset"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142018/array-gera-erro-undefined-offset)

Comment: PERFEITO! OBRIGADO!

Comment: Por nada , se te respondeu marque essa minha explicação como resposta da questão .
Boa sorte no desenvolvimento ai!